# UIViewController containment crashing

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I am fiddling with some code to try and get UIViewController containment working (in an iPad app).

The scenario is as follows: I have a view that I'd like to display a second view on top of.  I'd like to have a second (different) UIViewController manage all the interactions with the second view.  The first view will load the second view on the press of a button.  When the button is pressed the following code runs in the first controller:

```
-(void)displayPropertyView // <-button triggers this
{
    // Need to instantiate a new view and add it to the main editor view.
    HPSQuestionListController* questionListController = [ [ HPSQuestionListController alloc ] init ];
    [self.view addSubview:questionListController.view];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:questionListController.view];
    [self pushViewController:questionListController animated:YES];

}
-(void)pushViewController:(UIViewController*)controller animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self addChildViewController:controller];
    //[controller didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    if (YES)
    {
        [self transitionFromViewController:self 
                          toViewController:controller 
                                  duration:1.0 
                                   options:nil 
                                animations:^{}
                                completion:^(BOOL finished){
            [controller didMoveToParentViewController:self];
        }];
    }
}
```

The app crashes on the transitionFromViewController line with:

> Children view controllers  and
>    must have a common parent view
>   controller when calling -[UIViewController
>   transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:]'

Anyone know how to solve this?  My understanding of UIViewController containment is that I can have two controllers managing two views at the same time.  Is this wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The child view controllers should have the same parent container view controller (that's what the error message is saying). To add a child view controller use this code in the container view controller:

```
[self addChildViewController:myVC1];
[myVC1 didMoveToparentViewController:self];
```

In the container view controller you can use `transitionFromViewController`

```
[self transitionFromViewController:myVC1 toViewController:myVC2 duration:2.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
  [myVC1 removeFromParentViewController];
  [myVC2 didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}];
```

You are trying to do stuff that doesn't make so much sense, `self` is not the container view controller in your code.

For a full example see: https://github.com/toolmanGitHub/stackedViewControllers